# Rules and logic programming with time as parameter: what language to use?

Tags: prolog, rules, clips

I am (hobby) programming a kind of scoreboard for a game with rules similar to ice hockey. So far, all ok with python and classes and methods (OOP; I am NOT good, but can survive the coding). Is there any possibility to use another ruly language with dynamic parameters like time? prolog? clips?
In the 1980 I was already reading Prolog.. so, wondering it did not found more adept, but currently digging more into it. So, if anyboding has experience with "rules state machine depending of time" written in Prolog or CLIPS, I would be glad to hear where to find some advices in the NET or here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I would recommend asking about this on [reddit](http://reddit.com/r/prolog) where we can have a conversation about it rather than here, where this isn't close enough to a straightforward question to have a straightforward and correct answer.